# Export xls file using php

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I want to export data in xls file, i have done this but problem is that all data are not tab format, all data comes with ',' seprated,
I did not what is wrong with my code,i have paste my code here please check and give me right solution

```
$column = array("id", "name","description","status","cname","agency","phone","website");
    $writecolumn = array("ID", "Artis Name","Description","Status","Category Name","Agency Name","Phone Number","Website");
    $csv_export='';
    $categoryname=$results[0]['cname'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
    {
        $csv_export.= '"'.$writecolumn[$i].'",';
    }
    $csv_export.= "\n";
    for($j = 0; $j < count($results); $j++)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
        {
        $csv_export.= '"'.$results[$j][$column[$i]].'",'; 
        } 
        $csv_export.= "\n";
    }
    $filename = $categoryname."-Category-Artist-Data.xls";
    }
    else
    {
    $csv_export.= "\n";
    $csv_export.= "No Record Found";
    $filename = "Blank.xls";
    }

    header('Content-type: application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    echo $csv_export;
    exit;
```

And my array like this

```
    Array
   (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 529
        [name] => Fabiana Karla
        [description] => O orÃ§amento abaixo serÃ¡ enviado diretamente para o empresÃ¡rio exclusivo do artista ou agente autorizado. Tenha sempre o melhor preÃ§o e a seguranÃ§a de estar negociando direto com os empresÃ¡rios oficiais dos artistas.
        [status] => 0
        [cname] => Comediante
        [agency] => 
        [phone] => 
        [website] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 530
        [name] => Fafy Siqueira
        [description] => O orÃ§amento abaixo serÃ¡ enviado diretamente para o empresÃ¡rio exclusivo do artista ou agente autorizado. Tenha sempre o melhor preÃ§o e a seguranÃ§a de estar negociando direto com os empresÃ¡rios oficiais dos artistas.
        [status] => 0
        [cname] => Comediante
        [agency] => 
        [phone] => 
        [website] => 
    )

   )
```

You can see image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/LolAS.png

Comment: Change $csv_export.= '"'.$writecolumn[$i].'",'; to $csv_export.= '"'.$writecolumn[$i].'"\t';

Comment: this will print \t with the xls file data

Comment: can you paste all the code so I can check it.

Comment: i have pase all code here like array from query result and columns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this this will work for you

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
    {
        $csv_export.= $writecolumn[$i]."\t" ;
    }
    $csv_export.= "\n";
    for($j = 0; $j < count($results); $j++)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
        {
        $csv_export.= $results[$j][$column[$i]]."\t"; 
        } 
        $csv_export.= "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. You need to change "," woth "\t" for tab  seprated

```
    $column = array("id", "name","description","status","cname","agency","phone","website");
    $writecolumn = array("ID", "Artis Name","Description","Status","Category Name","Agency Name","Phone Number","Website");
    $csv_export='';
    $categoryname=$results[0]['cname'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
    {
        $csv_export.= '"'.$writecolumn[$i].'"\t';
    }
    $csv_export.= "\n";
    for($j = 0; $j < count($results); $j++)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
        {
        $csv_export.= '"'.$results[$j][$column[$i]].'"\t'; 
        } 
        $csv_export.= "\n";
    }
    $filename = $categoryname."-Category-Artist-Data.xls";
    }
    else
    {
    $csv_export.= "\n";
    $csv_export.= "No Record Found";
    $filename = "Blank.xls";
    }

    header('Content-type: application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    echo $csv_export;
    exit;
```

Comment: I was using this to create TSV files you can change it (\t) to whatever format your want like comma (,) semicolon (;) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "\t" for tab and "\n" for new line. it is working you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. it is working.

```
$results = array('0'=>array('id'=>529,'name'=>'Fabiana Karla','description'=>'O orÃ§amento abaixo serÃ¡ enviado diretamente para o empresÃ¡rio exclusivo do artista ou agente autorizado. Tenha sempre o melhor preÃ§o e a seguranÃ§a de estar negociando direto com os empresÃ¡rios oficiais dos artistas.','status'=>0,'cname'=>'Comediante','agency'=>'','phone'=>'','website'=>''),'1'=>array('id'=>530,'name'=>'Fafy Siqueira Karla','description'=>'O orÃ§amento abaixo serÃ¡ enviado diretamente para o empresÃ¡rio exclusivo do artista ou agente autorizado. Tenha sempre o melhor preÃ§o e a seguranÃ§a de estar negociando direto com os empresÃ¡rios oficiais dos artistas.','status'=>0,'cname'=>'Comediante','agency'=>'','phone'=>'','website'=>''));

$column = array("id", "name","description","status","cname","agency","phone","website");
$writecolumn = array("ID", "Artis Name","Description","Status","Category Name","Agency Name","Phone Number","Website");
$csv_export='';

for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
{
    $csv_export.= '"'.$writecolumn[$i].'",';
}
$csv_export.= "\n";

for($j = 0; $j < count($results); $j++)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
    {
       $csv_export.= '"'.$results[$j][$column[$i]].'",'; 
    }
    $csv_export.= "\n";
}

if(!empty($results)){
$filename = $categoryname."-Category-Artist-Data.xls";
}
else
{
$csv_export.= "\n";
$csv_export.= "No Record Found";
$filename = "Blank.xls";
}

header('Content-type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $csv_export;
exit;
```

?>